# Query SUM mysql with if condition

Tags: mysql

I have some table in mysql database like this.

```
id | product | warehouse | price | date_shipping
------------------------------------------------
1 | Salt | 15 | 300 | 2017-03-08
2 | Salt | 15 | 300 | 2017-03-09
```

I want to `SUM` that column **price** with several condition. This is the condition.

From the **product** salt if the warehouse is have same id I don't want to `SUM` price value.

This is my second condition.

```
id | product | warehouse | price | date_shipping
------------------------------------------------
1 | Salt | 15 | 300 | 2017-03-08
2 | Salt | 18 | 300 | 2017-03-09
```

From the **product** salt if the warehouse is have different id I want to `SUM` price value.

This is the result what I want from the query.

From first condition :

```
salt | 15 | 300
```

From second condition :

```
salt | 15,18 | 600
```

This is query what I have doing.

```
SELECT product, GROUP_CONCAT(warehouse SEPARATOR ',') as warehouse, SUM(price)
FROM db_product
```

Somebody can help me with this ? Thank you.

Comment: If two salts have the same warehouse, then whose `price` do you want to use?  What is the logic?

Comment: From the first `date_shipping` in that example use **2017-03-08** @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

Your problem requires two aggregations.  The first one identifies, for each product in a warehouse, the record having the earliest shipping date.  Then, a second aggregation is needed to group concatenate the warehouses for each product.

```
SELECT t.product,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t.warehouse) AS warehouses,
       SUM(t.price) AS total
FROM
(
    SELECT t1.product,
           t1.warehouse,
           t1.price
    FROM db_product t1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT product, warehouse, MIN(date_shipping) AS min_date_shipping
        FROM db_product
        GROUP BY product, warehouse
    ) t2
        ON t1.product       = t2.product AND
           t1.warehouse     = t2.warehouse AND
           t1.date_shipping = t2.min_date_shipping
) t
GROUP BY t.product
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Okay, I will try it first.